# prediction interval of a new prediction out of a weighted linear regression model

Tags: prediction, prediction-interval, weighted-regression

This question is based on the example 11.1 out of the book Applied linear statistical models of Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter and Li. You can find the [data here](http://www.stat.lsu.edu/exstweb/statlab/datasets/KNNLData/CH11TA01.txt).

First they calculate a simple linear model:

```r
Call:
lm(formula = Bloodpressure ~ Age, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.4786  -5.7877  -0.0784   5.6117  19.7813 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 56.15693    3.99367  14.061  < 2e-16 ***
Age          0.58003    0.09695   5.983 2.05e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 8.146 on 52 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4077,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3963 
F-statistic: 35.79 on 1 and 52 DF,  p-value: 2.05e-07
```

But the residual plots show that the variance of the error term increases with predictor `Age`. Long story short, they use weights to account for this heteroscedasticity and they get:

```r
Call:
lm(formula = Bloodpressure ~ Age, data = data, weights = weights)

Weighted Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0230 -0.9939 -0.0327  0.9250  2.2008 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 55.56577    2.52092  22.042  < 2e-16 ***
Age          0.59634    0.07924   7.526 7.19e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1.213 on 52 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5214,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5122 
F-statistic: 56.64 on 1 and 52 DF,  p-value: 7.187e-10
```

Now my question is, how do I calculate the prediction error if I get a new patient with `age=25`? Is it correct that the prediction interval will be smaller for lower ages?